# How to show git commit using number of commits since a tag

Tags: git

With `git describe` you can get the number of commits since the last tag.  If you only had the tag and the number of commits what is the best way to show the commit that was described?

I know you could use `git log tag..` and pipe it to a a script that does the counting but I was hoping for a more elegant solution similar to `git show tag~n`.

To add more context, we are planning using `git describe` to create release numbers, for example with

```
$ git describe
v1.5-39-g5ede964
```

we would use foo_1.5.39.   What we would like to do is knowing 1.5.39 means the 39th commit after the v1.5 tag, find that commit, i.e. find g5ede964.   As pointed out in a comment, the 39th commit after v1.5 may not be unique.  So perhaps a better way to ask this is what is the best way to find all commits X such that if HEAD was pointing to X `git describe` would return 
`v1.5-39-*****`.

Comment: You can do `git show tag~n` to show the n-th commit before that tag. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something …

Comment: I believe moving forward from tag is not possible. Every commit (except the initial one) in git has at least one parent, so you can go backwards by commits. On the other hand this tagged commit (as any other commit) might be a parent of more than one commit and it doesn't have any reference to its children, so the only way you can move is from children to parent and not vice versa.

Comment: @KL-7 Thanks, that makes sense.  I added more context to my question on what we are trying to achieve.  Based on your point that parents don't reference children, I'm guessing there is no way to to do this.  In which case, if you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that in `v1.5-39-g5ede964` the `g` means [that this is git](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-describe), and the `5ede964` is the SHA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible in the general case. The number of commits alone can't tell you anything if there are any merges in your history.

For example, given the following repo structure:

```
a - b - c - d - h
  \           /
    e - f - g
```

With a tag put on `a`, the outputs of `git describe d` and `git describe g` are identical save for the SHA1:

```
> git describe d
tag-3-ge8dca33
> git describe g
tag-3-g4fecc2e
```

That said, if you don't have a bunch of parallel branches going on at once, then you may be able to resolve a given commit number back to a single commit, but if you have even a single active side branch at the time of your tag then this may not work.

If you need reliable release numbers, you should stick to explicit tags.

Comment: It's even worse than this.  After you merge, many commits must get renumbered because the commits will be interleaved in some fashion. 
 I'm going with Linus Torvalds and using the `git describe` output as-is for my version number.

Answer (score 40):

Try

```
git rev-list tag..HEAD --count
```

OR

```
git rev-list tag.. --count
```

They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

If you are looking for the number of commits since the last tag, the following worked for me

```
git rev-list  `git rev-list --tags --no-walk --max-count=1`..HEAD --count
```

Comment: Beware that `git rev-list --tags --no-walk --max-count=1` will find the most recent tag, but that tag is not necessarily an ancestor of HEAD.  It could be from a separate branch.

Answer (score 5):

You can:

```
git log --oneline tag.. | wc -l
```

this will give you the number of commits

Comment: But I want the nth commit since a tag, not the number of commits since a tag.  Basically the inverse of git describe.

Comment: Don't use `git log` for scripting, use `git rev-list` instead

Comment: @knittl, could you add some detail to that thought? Why favor ``rev-list`` over ``log``?  
I'm in a situation  where scripting with ``log`` appears to be the way to go, and would like to stick to best practices.

Comment: @UrsReupke: `log` is a porcelain command its output format might change with future versions of git (e.g. with the new i18n efforts). `rev-list` is guaranteed to remain output-compatible across different git versions. Of course, it's often easier to script around `log`: for quick one-time or personal scripts this might be OK.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following, if you want to get the number of commits since last tag.

```
git rev-list $(git describe --abbrev=0)..HEAD --count
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602682/1531708) explained, this is generally not possible. To solve the problem for special cases he mentioned:

> That said, if you don't have a bunch of parallel branches going on at once, then you may be able to resolve a given commit number back to a single commit, but if you have even a single active side branch at the time of your tag then this may not work.

you can use the following command (with `n` being the number of commits since the tag)

```
git rev-list tag..HEAD --reverse | awk NR==n
```

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best way to find all commits X such that if `HEAD` was pointing to X `git describe` would return  `v1.5-39-*****`

is still the wrong question. The right question is

> how to find all commits X such that if HEAD was pointing to X an ordinary `git describe` **could ever have returned** `v1.5-39-*****`

and it's not all that easy to answer that. Still, absent enemy action this procedure will list the right commit maybe among some other possibilities:

```
ancestor=v1.5 n=39
git rev-list --all --reverse --topo-order --parents --ancestry-path ^$ancestor \
| awk ' function minmore(       i) {
                for ( i=2; i <= NF; ++i )
                        if ( gen[$i] > gen[$1] ) 
                                gen[$1]=gen[$i]
                return ++gen[$1]
        }
        minmore()<=n {
                print "[[ $(git rev-list --count "ancestor".."$1") == "n" ]] &&"
                print "         git describe --match="ancestor" "$1 }
      ' ancestor=$ancestor n=$n \
# | sh    # lose the first `#` here to actually run the generated checks
```

The reason for the uncertainty and complexity is that `git describe` is just trying to get a reasonable base, so (see [its docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)) it'll pick the most recent of the closest current tags it can see, and count how many additional commits there are in the described history, and generate a moniker that way.  For examples, new tags can change its preferred base such that a bare `git describe` would no longer generate that moniker; and while SHA's are immutable, references can be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the number of commits between these two commit.

$ git log --oneline 8a32722def6b80e343...e817c082323e65bb1053

Answer (score 0):

You can now do so using

```
git show v1.5-39-g5ede964
```

and it will print the info about the commit, e.g.

```
commit 335ceedde1a2d61e48eb891b9f51a344705ee5af
Merge: 57628284 3b7eef9e
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
Date:   Wed Dec 20 18:00:56 2023 +0200
```