# Find the first commit with tag name matching a pattern

Tags: git

I am trying to find the first tag that has a certain expression (for example, starting with "v") and to get that commit SHA. We start at a certain commit and go back in time to find the first tag that corresponds to that expression.

Like this:

```
   (v1.0.3)     (fix)     (START)(HEAD)
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 ---5 --- 6 --- 7
```

- v1.0.3 is a tag
- fix is a tag
- START is the commit where we start searching from

This would return 4, since START to v1.0.3 is 4 commits.

I have found some resources like these:

https://atech-mobile.com/blog/git-how-count-commits

[How to show git commit using number of commits since a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595391/how-to-show-git-commit-using-number-of-commits-since-a-tag)

The first one didnt work for me because this needs to run on WINDOWS and the 2nd one I just didn't get to work. (It's been a long day, I can't really explain why).

Hopefully this makes sure that the question wont be marked as duplicate.

It has to run on Windows so answers that run on Windows are preferred.

Comment: by "first", do you mean the closest to start?

Comment: @max630 Yes, going back in time (Starting at 6) to 2 (v1.0.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you describing looks very much like "git describe":

```
$ git describe --tags --match 'v*'
v2.16.1.windows.1-66-g72409919f5
```

The "66" there is just the number of commits after the latest tag matching the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--tags=` option on `git log`. From the man page:

```
       --tags[=<pattern>]
       Pretend as if all the refs in refs/tags are listed on the command
       line as <commit>. If <pattern> is given, limit tags to ones
       matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the
       end is implied.
```

To find everything that starts with `v`, you can use `git log --tags=v*` (or omit the star, since it would be implied)

Comment: I have read that using `log` for finding commits is bad, `rev-list` should be used for that. Correct me if I am wrong?

Also, this resulted in 0 results. @max630 's answer solved my question

Comment: Glad to hear it! I'd love to know the source for not using log for finding commits :)